# Open login dialog on MDI form

Tags: java, swing

Please how do I open a login dialog on MDI form to allow user login before getting access, I have been online several time but not getting it.

Comment: Please put some "meat" into your question, including telling the details of your problem, showing your code attempt, using that attempt to make the question much more specific. As written, your question looks to be a request for a complete private tutorial on using dialogs, and that is a bit overly broad for this (or any) site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without providing more specific information on how the login should look like you ought not to expect a very specific answer, but this is what comes to my mind:

In the main method of your application you insert some code that provides a password and maybe a user name prompt before anything else. If you do not mind the password to be masked with asterisks, you can use `JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter username:");` and a similar invoke for the password, otherwise you will have to build your own window for this task. In case you do not know how to do that, [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) might help you, as for sure this board is no platform to teach the use of basic swing components.

After the password and user name prompt you evaluate the given Strings (e.g. with a HashMap) and find out if the given password fits the given name. Then an `if`-clause can terminate the application with `System.exit()` if this would not be the case.

Comment: Good that I could help you. Please mark the question as answered if that is the case so that others are clear about its status.